# Let's golf our [TeX]

Tags: discussion, tags

I accidentally created the tag [tex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex). I untagged my question, so it now has `0` questions. Can we kill it with fire?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to do that. Unused tags are regularly removed automatically.